# Conditional view in SwiftUI doesn't compile

Tags: view, conditional-statements, swiftui

I'd like to create a settings form with toggles that reveal more toggles for detail customization if turned on. But the bellow simple code doesn't compile: "Segmentation fault: 11". What is wrong with the code?

```
import SwiftUI

struct Settings: View {
    @State var voiceOver = true
    @State var voiceOverStart = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Voice Over")) {
                    Toggle(isOn: $voiceOver) {
                        Text("Voice Over")
                    }
                    if voiceOver == true {
                        VStack {
                            Toggle(isOn: $voiceOverStart) {
                                Text("Start Bell")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Settings"))
        }
    }
}
```

Update: Commenting out the if statements, the code compiles... But of course without the desired behaviour...

```
                    // if voiceOver == true {
                        VStack {
                            Toggle(isOn: $voiceOverStart) {
                                Text("Start Bell")
                            }
                        }
                    // }
```

Comment: It compiles and runs fine for me. I'm using Xcode 11, beta 4. What about you?

Comment: Me too... This is strange.

Comment: Try cleaning you build directory, if problem persists, restart Xcode or even your Mac. If it still persists, try commenting some bits of code, until the error goes away and see if you can rewrite that part.

Comment: Alright, did clean the build directory and restarted the machine. I still get the same error. Then I commented out the if statement and it works...

Comment: That's unfortunate. A  segmentation fault in the compiler is never **your** fault. Try to rewrite your if statement. For example, try putting it inside a Group {}. Rewriting other parts of your code can also make the error go away. Encapsulating in subviews can also make the compiler act differently. These are just some ideas, you'll need to get creative. Good luck!

Comment: Just noticed, that the navigation bar title "Settings" is not showing up, the space is reserved, but there is no text. Something is really weird here...

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! I will probably wait and check the "Segmentatio fault" issue again when Beta 5 is out.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment as I made a typo I could not edit (too much  time passed). I meant to say `.navaigationBarTitle()` need to modify a descendant view of the NavigationView, not the NavigationView itself. This is how different pushed views get different titles.